# XCode 12: No persisted cache on this platform

Tags: ios, widgetkit

I am trying to develop an iOS 14 Widget in Simulator but each time I run the app I get the below warning.

```
MobileGestaltCache.c:38: No persisted cache on this platform.
```

This however breaks nothing but not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Commenting to say I am seeing this too. Never seen it before. I'm overriding the App struct in a SwiftUI life cycle project. Is that what you are doing? `struct myApp: App { ... init() { try! setupDatabase() } ...var body: Some scene ...`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the full log reads

> libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltCache.c:38: No persisted cache on this
> platform.

The interesting thing is `libMobileGestalt`.
In [this post](https://blog.timac.org/2018/1126-deobfuscated-libmobilegestalt-keys-ios-12/), a lot of infos are given about it. It says e.g.:

> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib is a private Apple library describing
> the capabilities of the iOS device, as well as some runtime
> information: system version, build version, device type, current
> status of the airplane mode, …
> The implementation is similar to a
> key-value database and the library exposes a simple function to
> retrieve the value for a specified key:
> id MGCopyAnswer(NSString
> *inKey);
> When calling this method with a key, it returns the associated value stored in the database, or nil if the key does not
> exist.

I don’t know if one can read out this way interesting information, at least one shouldn’t, since the contents of this private database can change any time.

Obviously, this library writes also logs, and in this case some info about the device used.
One can surely ignore it.